# windows server CLT vs CAL

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

What's the difference between windows server CAL and CLT license for attached workstations?
For example i have Microsoft Windows Server Standard 2008 R2 64Bit 10 Clt and vendor claims it can be run on server plus 10 workstations without limitations. Moreover if this is BOX version does this automatically mean the workstations are BOX too?

Comment: The "10 Clt" is the vendor abbreviation for "10 Client Licenses" aka CALs. There's no such thing as "CLT" in MS Licensing terms.

Answer (score 1):

License questions really should be directed back to the manufacturer. Regardless of what anyone tells you, the only information you should bank on is what you get directly from them. When you talk to them document it, dates, times, who you talked to etc if you're worried about any of the legal aspects.